# How do I link my twisted chat to my github website?

Tags: python, twisted, github-pages

I made a twisted TCP based chat with python. I did all the testing on localhost.

```
    class Protocol(twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver):

        def connectionMade(self):
            self.host = self.transport.getPeer().host
            print(self.host)


    class Factory(twisted.internet.protocol.Factory):
        protocol = Protocol

    factory = Factory()       
    twisted.internet.reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
    twisted.internet.reactor.run()
```

Now I would like to put it online so that anyone with an internet connection can use the client side. I started by making  github page (the page is named username.github.io ) how do I link the webpage to the actual python chat server?

Comment: github pages are for static content. you can't host your server there

Comment: What URI scheme did you register with IANA for your chat protocol?